# Problem with Public-key Authentication

Tags: ssh

I've created new ssh keys on my dev box a while ago. I did:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@mail.com"

I copy the key to my shared host.

Now I need to connect using the credentials on the key right ?

What should I write on the command line, in order to connect by using those credentials now?

Please advice, I'm a little lost here.

K. Regards,
MEM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fire up a terminal and you ssh the host

```
ssh username@host.domain.something
```

if you have your credentials on the server side you ll be asked about the signature of the host and if you have a passprase you will need to provide it(which you don't as I can get from your keygen).

A bit more inside information in your home directory /home/username/ there is a folder called .ssh which you can reveal with ctrl+h. There you can find all your keys. The keys with extention .pub are the ones you should use in case someones askes you for your key. In the filename also its included the algorithm of encryption.

Comment: @Chris-Top - I have no clue about the command that I've used. What does the -C or -r mean. I intend to have a passprase. I have provide it (as I recall), after doing this command, it ask me, and I wrote one. Twice. I found that, as you said, that I need to use my shared host ssh USER but, after this key is passed to the authorized_key file, I can use the PASSWORD that was created at key par generation time, INSTEAD of the one provided on my host. Is this precise? At this moment, I do ssh myuser@mydomain.com and I get instantly connected, without any password prompt. Why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mem ssh-keygen -t type [-C comment ] this is how its translated your command.

Comment: @mem In your sever your will find a file called ssh_config, in most distrubitions like ubuntu its under /etc/ssh/ssh_config, there you can find and uncomment or comment on what you want (password enabled or not)
 
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
 
to
 
StrictHostKeyChecking no

Comment: @Chris-top: Thanks. I have this key configurated on my system, and on the remove shared host as well. It seems that, I don't need to tell Ubuntu to recall my password, by using: ssh-agent bash and
ssh-add; It seems that Ubuntu does this already somehow? Is this correct ? Please advice.

Comment: @Chris-top: My previous answer was wrote without knowing your last comment. Thanks for pointing that out. I just wanted to know if I needto do: ssh-agent bash and ssh-add OR, I could well forget it. I believe this last one is the case, I just need some time to figure this out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mem I fall asleep yesterday, so to wrap it all together, ssh-agent instead of ssh is a way the provide the passphrase without having to write it all the time, especially with connections with multiple servers. ssh-add on the other hand is used in order to add your key to the authorized_hosts. ssh-add -l will reveal your existing identities.

Comment: @Chris-Top: Thanks. And, as far as I can tell, and for the sake of clarification: Since Ubuntu already runs ssh-agent when the system starts, I DON'T need to type that command NOR to create a bash process for it. Correct?

Comment: @MEM nope you just run ssh from console or any interface you use the socket is already reserved.